# Do unit tests unnecessarily obfuscate code, or is there a better way?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I have been working in an organization that puts a fair amount of pressure on devs to write and maintain unit tests. While it's not something I've done a whole lot in the past, I like the idea and believe any serious project should have some level of unit testing, especially for self container class libraries that lend themselves to such testing.

However, I've also found that what was once very simple, readable code is made into a monstrosity of factories and interfaces. At the simplest case, a service wrapper:

**No unit tests**

```
class ShazamService
{
   private string url;

   public ShazamService(string url) { this.url = url; }

   string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data)
   {
       return HttpHelper.Upload(url, mp3Data).Response;
   }
}

class Program
{
   public static int Main(string [] args)
   {
      var svc = new ShazamService("http://www.shazam.com");
      Console.Writeline(svc.IdentifySong(args[0].ToByteArray());
   }
}
```

**Unit testable version**

```
public interface IShazamService
{
   public string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data);
}

public class ShazamClassFactory
{
   private string url;

   public ShazamClassFactory(string url) { this.url = url; }

   public IShazamService GetInstance(bool test)
   {
      if (test)
      {
         return new ShazamServiceTest(this.url);
      }
      else
      {
         return new ShazamService(this.url);
      }
}

class ShazamService
{
   private string url;

   public ShazamService(string url) { this.url = url; }

   string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data)
   {
       return HttpHelper.Upload(url, mp3Data).Response;
   }
}

class Program
{
   public static int Main(string [] args)
   {
      var factory = new ShazamClassFactory("http://www.shazam.com");
      var svc = factory.GetInstance(false);
      Console.Writeline(svc.IdentifySong(args[0].ToByteArray());
   }
}
```

Not only is the code significantly longer in the 2nd one, but (to me) it's less clear - from Main I don't even know the type of the return value from CreateInstance if I need to look at an implementation detail, so I can't even F12 through the logic as easily. Also what would have been 1 file for the service now becomes 4 (factory, interface, 2 implementations), with header, documentation, etc.  Lastly, if I decide I want to change the constructor from `string url` to `string url, SongGenre genre`, I now need to check out, update, and check in  4 separate files, updating constructors, datamembers, documentation, etc for each.

Is this method of promoting unit testing the norm? Are there less intrusive options?  And, is it worth it? To my mind, by complicating the code, you increase dev time, and make errors more likely to sneak in, all for unit testing using fake objects that will only sorta-kinda test the code you're using.

Comment: This has nothing to do with unit testing, not sure where you came from with this factory and this horrible if inside of it. That's just bad design, it has nothing to do with unit testing at all.

Comment: Coding to Interfaces rather than concrete classes makes for more flexible code, regardless of unit testing. To avoid the ugly factory with a bool parameter, you might want to look at IoC so that you can set all this in a config file rather than cluttering your code.

Comment: Short answer: Unit testing shouldn't make your code suck harder, it should make your code suck less. Just figure out what your test needs to mock, and make it possible to pass that in. In this case, frex, instead of hard-coding `HttpHelper.Upload` you could pass in an `Upload` delegate. If you don't want to do that all the time, you could have two constructors, one (for testing) that takes the delegate and a chaining one that hard-codes it. I suggest posting a different question, "how do I make this testable"?

Comment: Writing tests is part of a process that begins with a requirement and ends with an implementation. Are you writing a test first, then just enough implementation of what's being tested to get the test to pass?

Comment: Unit tests are consumers of your code. If your code isn't friendly to consumers, that's a problem, or at the very least a smell.

Answer (score 8):

The code is unclear because it is badly written.

Dependency injection is done by injecting the class you want in a setter or a constructor, not by hardcoding the different options and using a `GetInstance(bool)` method to get your testing action.

Instead it should look more like this:

```
public class ShazamClassFactory
{
   private string url;
   private IShazamService _shazamService;

   public ShazamClassFactory(string url) { this.url = url; }

   public void SetShazamService(IShazamService service) {
      _shazamService = service;
   }

   public string GetSong(){
      return _shazamService.IdentifySong(url.ToByteArray());
   }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
var factory = new ShazamClassFactory("http://www.shazam.com");
factory.SetShazamService(new ShazamTestService());
var song = factory.GetSong();
```

Comment: This is a mostly good answer, but I don't understand why you've still got a factory class (or one that's at least named like a factory class), or why you've gone for setter over constructor injection

Comment: @BenAaronson: I just took over the `ShazamclassFactory` name; it's not an actual factory (no factory methods available). I took setter instead of constructor because the constructor already had a parameter and I wanted to keep it clear (both are perfectly fine ofcourse, although constructor is also my preference).

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see here is that it's not immediately clear what you're trying to test.

If you are writing code that *uses* a `ShazamService` then you can pass either a concrete implementation or a test implementation, depending on whether it's a unit test or not.

The use of a factory should be used if you need to control *when* an object gets created, and should not (imo) be the default pattern when passing in dependencies.

For your instance, a better option could be.

Service Interface

```
public interface IShazamService
{
    string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data);
}
```

Actual Live Interface

```
public class LiveShazamService : IShazamService
{
    private readonly string _url;

    public LiveShazamService(string url)
    {
        _url = url;
    }

    public string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data)
    {
        return HttpHelper.Upload(url, mp3Data).Response;
    }   
}
```

Test Interface (probably lives in your test project)

```
public class MockShazamService : IShazamService
{
    private readonly string _testData;

    public LiveShazamService(string testData)
    {
        _testData = testData;
    }

    public string IdentifySong(byte [] mp3Data)
    {
        return _testData;
    }   
}
```

Test Code

```
[Test]
public void ShouldParseTitleOfSong()
{
    // arrange
    var shazamService = new MockShazamService(
        "<html><title>Bon Jovi - Shock to the Heart</title></html>");

    var parser = new ShazamMp3Parser(shazamService);

    // act
    // this is just dummy input, 
    // we're not testing input in this specific test
    var result = parser.Parse(new byte[0]);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Bon Jovi - Shock to the Heart", result.Title);
}
```

Production Code

```
public class ShazamMp3Parser
{
    private readonly IShazamService _shazamService;

    public ShazamMp3Parser(IShazamService shazamService)
    {
        _shazamService = shazamService;
    }

    public ShazamParserResult Parse(byte[] mp3Data)
    {
        var rawText = _shazamService.IdentifySong(mp3Data);

        // bla bla bla (up to the viewer to implement properly)
        var title = rawText.SubString(24, 50);  

        return new ShazamParserResult { Title = title };
    }
}
```

Usage of Production Code

```
public static int Main(string [] args)
{
    var service = new LiveShazamService("http://www.shazam.com");

    var parser = new ShazamMp3Parser(service);

    var mp3Data = args[0].ToByteArray();

    Console.Writeline(parser.Parse(mp3Data).Title);
}
```

In this example, I am showing how to test code that depends upon the `IShazamService` (the `ShazamMp3Parser`), this lets you unit test the parsing of the title without having to make an internet connection and pull live data.  The mock service lets you simulate data and unit test how your parsing code works.

I did not implement the factory as I don't feel it's necessary in this scenario, but if you wanted to control when the service is instantiated, you could write a factory interface, followed by two implementations, one that constructs the live service and one that constructs the test one.

If you get brave later on, or you get sick of writing mock classes all over the place, you can use a mocking framework (like [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4)) to make your unit test writing faster.

```
[Test]
public void ShouldParseTitleOfSong()
{
    // arrange
    var mockShazamService = new Mock<IShazamService>();

    mockShazamService.Setup(x => x.IdentifySong(It.IsAny<byte[]>()))
                     .Returns("<html><title>Bon Jovi - Shock to the Heart</title></html>");

    var parser = new ShazamMp3Parser(mockShazamService.Object);

    // act
    var result = parser.Parse(new byte[0]);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Bon Jovi - Shock to the Heart", result.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). By providing an interface that abstract the factory itself, you can pass around a factory that creates test object or a factory that creates real objects and not have to instrument your code.